# Ruby taking up 99.3% CPU

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, cpu, rackspace-cloud

I'm running ruby 1.9.3 with rails on a Rackspace server.  Ruby has 12 processes and is taking up 99.3% of my servers CPU.  Is there any configuration file or option to either limit the number of processes and CPU it takes up or just make it use less CPU in general?  How should I start fixing this.

UPDATE: I'm using passenger with apache

Comment: I'd suggest that you limit this process in whatever way ubuntu suggests you schedule tasks.  Unfortunately I don't know how ubuntu suggests task scheduling.  It will likely require root privileges which may/may not be a concern as you are using a "cloud" environment.

Comment: What else would you like to run there?

Comment: Why do you assume that there is something in need of fixing? Tass's question is a good one. What, if anything, is being starved of CPU time in favor of the ruby processes?

Comment: 12 processes? that's a lot (depending on size of server and memory size, obviously)

Comment: I'm also running redis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue! There is a bug with New Relic and Resque workers (https://github.com/defunkt/resque/issues/578).  I'm using the New Relic Beta gem which solves this.  I replaced this: `gem 'newrelic_rpm'` with `gem 'newrelic_rpm', "~> 3.5.6.48.beta"`

Answer (score 3):

Are you running an application server?  Both Passenger, Unicorn, and other popular ruby app servers allow you to configure the maximum number of worker processes.  For example, if you wanted to cap the app server workers at 10 (vs. 12 you see):

For unicorn in the unicorn.rb config file, set:

```
worker_processes 10
```

For Passenger under nginx, in your config set:

```
http {
    ...
    passenger_max_pool_size 10;
}
```

For Passenger under Apache, in your Passenger/apache config:

```
PassengerMaxPoolSize 10
```

If this doesn't answer your question, tell us what application server or ruby infrastructure you are running.

Comment: I'm using passenger with apache

Comment: Added Passenger/Apache syntax.  Hope this solves your issue.  You need to tune the work pool size to fit the processor/memory constraints of your host.

Comment: Thanks! That helps with another issue I had :) The issue was with New Relic.  Ironic that the service that helps monitor server resources causes spikes in CPU :)